# ASP.NET / Telerik Webforms: How do you intercept and change the bound value of a column in a RadGrid?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I have some custom conversion and formatting to do for certain data on multiple Telerik `RadGrid`s throughout a web application.  Prior to using Telerik, I used the standard ASP.NET `GridView`.  To do my custom conversion and formatting while using the `GridView`, I derived a new class from `BoundField` and overrode the `FormatDataValue` and `GetValue` methods.  In this manner, I could intercept the value for a grid cell from the bound data source, change the value as the grid sees it, and apply my custom formatting rules.  Then whenever I needed this functionality for a particular grid column, I used my custom `BoundField`.

I do not see any method for the Telerik `GridBoundColumn` to override and intercept the point at which the grid fetches data from the bound data source (the equivalent to the GridView's `BoundField.GetValue` method).  *I need the cell data to appear to the Telerik grid to be value B for all functions - display, sorting, filtering, grouping, etc. - even though the corresponding data in the data source is value A, and I cannot alter the underlying data source in any way.*

Code snippets for what I was doing using the ASP.NET GridView's BoundField:

```
public class MyBoundField
    : BoundField
{
    protected override string FormatDataValue(object dataValue, bool encode)
    {
        if ( someCondition )
        {
            return MyFormatFunction(dataValue, encode);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.FormatDataValue(dataValue, encode);
        }
    }

    protected override object GetValue(Control controlContainer)
    {
        // Get the data bound value.
        object boundValue = base.GetValue(controlContainer);

        // Convert the value for the grid's usage.
        object convertedValue = MyConversionFunction(boundValue);

        return convertedValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<asp:GridView ... >
    <asp:BoundField .... />
    <custom:MyBoundField .... />
</asp:GridView>
```

Telerik option:

```
public class MyGridBoundColumn
    : GridBoundColumn
{
    protected override string FormatDataValue(object dataValue, GridItem item)
    {
        if ( someCondition )
        {
            return MyFormatFunction(dataValue, item);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.FormatDataValue(dataValue, item);
        }
    }

    // Override what method in order to convert the value for all grid functionality????
}
```

**Question:**
How do I do the equivalent of `BoundField.GetValue` with a Telerik GridBoundColumn within a RadGrid?  If there is no true equivalent, what are the available options?

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnItemDataBound event and modify the cell directly as shown here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-accessing-cells-and-rows.html.

Let's assume you have this markup:

```
        <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
            <MasterTableView>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="first" DataField="Notification"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

where the Notification field is present in your data source. Here is a sample server handler:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        dataItem["first"].Text = dataItem["first"].Text + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Note how the UniqueName of the column is used in the server code.

Comment: This approach certainly solves the issue for displaying the data with modification.  However, how does this address modifying the value that the grid uses for sorting and filtering?

Comment: I may have misread something. To update this - since displayed data and actual data differ, you should filter manually: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/filter-templates/defaultcs.aspx and http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-implementing-filtering-for-gridtemplatecolumns.html will show you how.